# Derivative Instantaneous rate of change

Tags: derivatives

Question:

The cumulative ticket sales for the $10$ days preceding a popular concert is given by $$S(x)=4x^2+50x+5000\qquad 1\le x \le 10.$$

Find the instantaneous rate of change in $S(x)$ when $x=3$.

Comment: I think I should used f(b)-f(a)/b-a

Comment: and using the f'(x)=lim...but really don't know where to start, was reading the notes and was confused with the velocity thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: The instantaneous rate of change of $S(x)=4x^2+50x+5000$ w.r.t. $x$ is given as $$\frac{dS}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(4x^2+50x+5000)=8x+50$$
Now, substitute $x=3$ to find $\frac{dS}{dx}$

Comment: 8(3)+50=74....Hope this is right!

Comment: Absolutely, you are correct.

Comment: Sir I thank you for helping, it takes nearly a whole day to figure it out.